# Drag images from Firefox to my application

Tags: .net, wpf, firefox, drag-and-drop

I can drag and drop images from Firefox to Windows Explorer and by that save the image. Can I somehow do the same in my own application, that is drag an image from Firefox to some part of my application and by that get the image into the application?

My applicaition is built with .NET 4 and WPF.

Edit:
John Koerner got me part of the way, but not exactly how I want it...

If I drag a file from Firefox to Windows Explorer, the file is saved exactly as it is on the website I'm dragging it from. That is, it has the same file name, file format and file size. It seems just like it is saved straight from the website, as if I had right-clicked it and choosen "Save as". The only thing I get is a path to a bitmap in a temp folder. Nice, but not quite what I want. I guess I could just take that bitmap and compress it to a JPEG or whatever, but I'd really prefer to get the original. Since this behavior is what I get when dragging an image to Windows Explorer, I figured maybe it is possible for me to get that in my own application.

Answer (score 2):

You have to allow drop on your window and then handle the drop event.  Then you can read the FileDrop to get the location of the file on disk and load it into an image or wherever else you need it.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.AllowDrop = true;
    this.Drop += new DragEventHandler(MainWindow_Drop);
}

void MainWindow_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(((string[])e.Data.GetData("FileDrop"))[0]));
    image1.Source = bi;

    // Get the different parameters available and see which work for you.
    foreach (var param in e.Data.GetFormats())
        Console.WriteLine(param);
}
```

Here is a list of params I got when I dragged from firefox to my App.  Filename or FilenameW may be of interest to you.  Use these strings with the GetData method to get the data you want.

```
text/x-moz-url
FileGroupDescriptor
FileGroupDescriptorW
FileContents
UniformResourceLocator
UniformResourceLocatorW
text/x-moz-url-data
text/x-moz-url-desc
text/uri-list
text/_moz_htmlcontext
text/_moz_htmlinfo
text/html
HTML Format
Text
UnicodeText
System.String
application/x-moz-nativeimage
DeviceIndependentBitmap
FileDrop
FileNameW
FileName
Preferred DropEffect
application/x-moz-file-promise-url
application/x-moz-file-promise-dest-filename
DragImageBits
DragContext
```

Comment: Thanks John! However, I've added some more info in my question to clearify the behavior I want.

Comment: @haagel I updated the answer to point you in the right direction.